# ORACLE - TO_NUMBER Function

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I have column `TEXT_INT` in my table and I would like convert to DECIMAL using TO_NUMBER Function. Unfortunately I am getting

> INVALID NUMBER ORA-722 error.

I doubt it may have characters in it. So Issued below query but there is no alphabets in `TEXT_INT`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM NANTHA_TABLE 
WHERE UPPER(TEXT_INT) != LOWER(TEXT_INT);
```

Would you please provide an idea to resolve this issue or ways to finding wrong data?

Comment: Check this article, it would be excellent for your case here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php .

Comment: It's possible that there are no characters but spaces inside some of your records. Please add your query that you tried in your question.

Comment: select * FROM NANTHA_TABLE where regexp_like(TEXT_INT,'[^0-9]');can you let me know the o/p of this query.?

Comment: You need to use Oracle's `regular expression` functions to solve this problem because the other solutions don't correctly handle strings like '12+3' or, as @KeyurPanchal mentioned, strings that have nothing but blank characters or strings that have tabs and such. The `regular expression` for catching all the problems is not too difficult. Keep in mind that the string '1e3' is a string that can be cast as a number. That is why you need an RE, because the whole specification for a valid number is lengthy but is made easier with REs.

Comment: What a bad idea to store a number in a string. What is this column allowed to contain? Only digits? A leading minus sign? A leading plus sign? A trailing minus sign? Thousand separators? A formula even? (I don't think you allow decimal separators, as the column is called *int*.)

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? I ask, because in 12.2, Oracle have extended the to_number, to_char, etc functions to cater for conversion errors: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/conversion-function-enhancements-12cr2, and that may be just what you need.

Answer (score 5):

### try this:

create function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function f_invalid_number(number_field in varchar2) return number as
  n_d number;
begin
  n_d := TO_number(number_field);
  return 0;
exception 
  when others then
    return 1;
end;
/
```

then you can check invalid data like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NANTHA_TABLE 
WHERE f_invalid_number(TEXT_INT) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you.

```
select your_wrong_col ,
       case
          when trim(TRANSLATE(your_wrong_col ,'0123456789','')) is null
             then 'numeric'
             else 'not_numeric'
       end as your_wrong_col
from YOUR_TABLE
where trim(TRANSLATE(your_wrong_col ,'0123456789','')) is not null;
```

Finds non-numeric  rows.

Comment: What about sign/thousand seperator/decimal period? All valid.

Comment: Or scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to find records where TEXT_INT column has characters other than number.

```
select  * from NANTHA_TABLE  where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TEXT_INT,'^[0-9]+$')
```

In case you are expecting more string symbols in your column which should be considered as valid you can include them in the NOT REGEXP_LIKE condition so those columns also don't appear in the query.

eg. If expecting a '-' symbol in the start of the string for some values:

```
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^-?[0-9.]+$') "
```

where

- '^' Begining
- '?' Zero or One occurance
- '+' One of More occurance
- '$' End of String

Please note i know that the decimals in my above query will be accepted even if counted twice. For that I propose a different solution to count the number of decimals in the string and throw error. If any1 can integrate it with the REGEXP you are most welcome. How to count number of decimals for check.

```
 LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) - LENGTH(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'.','')) > 1
```

To find more details about the REGEXP_LIKE please use the [following link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php).

Comment: Not bad but it doesn't cover the entire definition of an [allowable number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891). That's why I like the PL/SQL function approach. Oracle can change it's definition and the PL/SQL function would continue to work while the RE approach might have to change but it would at the very least have to be revisited.

Comment: @jeff6times7 I understand that. I like my approach because its more open. We see that the OP is using a string column as number instead of creating a number column which might suggest that hes/[or the person who created it] is expecting some extra special characters added with the number in this column. Anyway .. its a long shot. Just trying to put out a more open solution. However i too agree with the PL/SQL function approach for a more traditional number check.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Please read my whole answer. I have explained the decimal challenge as well. We can combine both the REGEXP & the decimal count query together.